# error message when inserting into table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert value in `product` table from `product2` table like this.

```
INSERT INTO product  
     SELECT * 
       FROM product2 
      WHERE product_code = 8002-25768;
```

But it is showing the following message .

> ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

please help me

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also add the tag 'sql' to your question.

Answer (score 0):

check if tables have same structure (the same number of columns and same type for columns at the same index)

Answer (score 0):

It means that `product` has *different* column count than `product2`; so either `product2` has *spare* columns or `product` has *unassigned* ones. I suggest rewriting  the query into

```
INSERT INTO product(p1, ..., pN)  
     SELECT column1, -- this will be written into p1
            ...
            columnN  -- this will be written into pN
       FROM product2 
         -- do you really want subtraction: 8002-25768 = -17766??? Probably '8002-25768'
      WHERE product_code = '8002-25768';
```

Please, notice that *each* `pK` target column corresponds to `columnK` source one.

Comment: You are right sir, it is '8002-25768' not subtraction .